# Is Java 6 SE available for Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: java, windows-server-2008

According to this [Oracle document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/system-configurations-135212.html), it seems that for Windows Server 2008 R2, Java 6 is only available as JFB (Java for business) and not as Java 6 SE.

Is this information correct?  If yes, what's the reason behind this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 6 SE can be installed and run on Windows Server 2008 R2 (I am using it).

However it is not officially supported by Oracle on this platform unless you have a Java for Business support contract.

Comment: Me too, I'm running both the 32-bit and 64-bit version of Java SE 6 on Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64) and it works without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running on a server, there are some benefits for using the JFB.

> Java for Business is a set of custom
>   Java SE revisions that gives companies
>   immediate access to critical fixes, a
>   longer roadmap for support, and
>   enterprise features that greatly
>   minimize the costs of deployment and
>   maintenance.

See here: http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/java-for-business-071123.html

The link you provided says that support is not available, I am not sure it that mean that JAVA 6 SE can't be installed, maybe it can but if you have a problem then they are not going to support it, you need to use JFB instead

Comment: That is the whole point, since you are running a server, they assume you are a business and are willing to pay for it.

Comment: If that is the case why is Windows Server 2008 R1/RHEL supported under Java SE? Perhaps they haven't fully qualified 2008 R2 yet?

Comment: OK but why Java 6 SE is available for "Windows Server 2008 Enterprise (SP1, SP2)" then?

Comment: Yes could be that they didn't qualified it yet, but this is interesting since 2008 R2 and win 7 share the same kernel  Build 7600

Answer (score 1):

This is just saying that R2 is not a supported configuration, not that Java 6 is not available or that it will not work.  I do not have an R2 machine around here but I ran Java 6 on an 64 bit 2008 machine (R1 if you will) and had no problems.  I just downloaded the Windows x64 version of the JDK and ran production applications in a JBoss container and never had an issue.